# Proving that $ 19\mid 5^{2n-1} \cdot 2^{n+1} + 3^{n+1} \cdot 2^{2n-1}$ using modular methods

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How can I prove that  expression using modular methods ?

Comment: What have you tried? What are you stuck on? Please edit your question to include more information.

Comment: I tried to simplify the expression and settled on $2^n(4 \cdot5^{2n}+ 15 \cdot 3^n2^n) \equiv 0 \pmod {19}$

Comment: Rewrite as $\ a\, 50^{n-1}\! + b\, 12^{n-1}\! \equiv (a\!+\!b)\,12^{n-1}\equiv 0\,$ by $\,50\equiv 12,\,a+b\equiv 0\pmod{\!19},\,$ by linked congruence rules. $\ \ $

Comment: Yes I did it  with $12^{n-1}$, thank you